# TikZ Application

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to learn drawing in latex with TikZ for simple shapes. But when I want to draw shapes in 3D or special shapes I am confused. I think there are some applications to make it easier and convert an image to latex code. Can you give me suggest for the application?

Comment: Does the linked question cover what you are asking or is there something more specific you need to tackle?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using TikZ directly. It's not that difficult.

The [TikZ documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) contains some very good introductions in the first chapter for different applications. After reading the first ("Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students" pages 29--46) you should know the basics and a little more.

TikZ supports specifying 3D coordinates, as described in chapter 13  "Specifying Coordinates" on pages 131, 132.
By default the x-axis points right, the y-axis upwards and the z-axis out of the screen. In the following example I have changed this so that the x-axis points out of the screen, the y-axis to the right and the z-axis upwards:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    3D/.style={
        x={(-3.85mm, -3.85mm)},
        y={(1cm, 0cm)},
        z={(0cm, 1cm)},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3D]
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[below left] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[below right] {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]