# Drawing a line, a plane, and a sphere, and their points of intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code renders a sphere and a plane. How do I get the plane to be at the south pole of the sphere - and centered? On this diagram, I would like to draw a ray from the north pole `N` through the point `P = (-\sqrt{3}, -1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2})` and through the point `Q = ((-\sqrt{3}/7)(-8+2\sqrt{2}), (-\sqrt{2}/14)(-8+2\sqrt{2}), -2)` of intersection between the ray and the plane, and I would like to mark `N`, `P`, and `Q` with a dot. (I want to keep the code in a `TikZ` environment.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\shade[ball color=blue!25] (0,0,0) circle (2);
\fill[opacity=0.25] (-3,0,4) -- (-1,2,4) -- (5,2,4) -- (3,0,4) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tikz uses a painter's algorithm for drawing, what is written (in code) first is drawn first and code afterwards is drawn on top. For positioning, x and y are on the paper, z goes into the paper; so you have to re-order your coordinates to make it work. So (0,-2,0) would be the south pole of your sphere; (-2,-2,-2) the left front corner. This code: `\fill[opacity=0.25] (-2,-2,-2) -- (2,-2,-2) -- (2,-2,2) -- (-2,-2,2) -- cycle;
\shade[ball color=blue!25] (0,0,0) circle (2);` should get you going.

Comment: If you prefer the axis to point in other directions you can easily change the definitions as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367992/120953).

Comment: I am interested in drawing the ray from 'N' through 'P' and 'Q'.

Comment: If you look in the pgfmath section of the tikz manual, you will see that it use sqrt(3) instead of \sqrt{3}.  Other than that, it should work for \coordinate or \fill[black] circle(2pt) node[above right]{P}; etc.

Comment: @John Kormylo  I was stating the ray that I wanted using `TeX` commands. I know that to code in `TikZ`, the coordinates would be specified with commands like `sqrt(3)` and `-1/sqrt(2)`.

Comment: @John Kormylo  The `y-axis` comes out of the paper. Suppose I simply want to draw the line `y=2x` on the plane `z=0`. How would that be drawn? Typically, the perspective for such drawings is off the `y-axis` so that the `x-axis` and `y-axis` are not perpendicular to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example could be useful to you: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/ .

Comment: Is it too long as a comment?

Comment: No, @ArtificialStupidity. I'm still not allowed to comment other people's answers (because I didn't reach 50 yet). But (since I was studying the example from the link I have posted) I thought it could be helpful to answer user7493's question. If this is considered inappropriate by the community, I can delete my answer.

Comment: @Alex Yes, the code of one of these drawings is what I want.